# How can I replace or delete a character from a string in React JS like normal Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a string that contains multiple '-'. I want to remove the all '-'. I tried the following way but it didn't work.

```
var str = "baa7f3b17ffc-4216-bfbc-8e9f70f26984"
var new_str = str.replace('-', '')
```

How can I remove or replace all the '-'? Is there any simple function for that?

Comment: Why is there 2 `)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove globally and remove the second parenthesis

```
 var str = "baa7f3b17ffc-4216-bfbc-8e9f70f26984";
 var new_str = str.replace(/-/g, '');
 console.log(new_str);
```